# Change domain in D3

Tags: onclick, resize, dns, d3.js

I am returning data via SQL to an asp.net label as comma-delimited.  I am pulling x, y, and c data.  I am using the third variable to tell me what set the data belong to (I have multiple sets).  Now, these sets have different domains, so let's use a toy example:

X = [1,0.5,0.75,0.8; 10,5,7.5,8; 100, 50, 75, 80]

Y = [2,3,4,5; 20,30,40,50; 200, 300, 400, 500]

C = [1,1,1,1; 2,2,2,2; 3,3,3,3]

I have it set up so when the user selects a set from the dropdown, I show only that set by running

```
.attr("r", function (d) { if(d.c == $('#pick').val()) return 1; else return 0})
```

But of course the appropriate scales to show these are quite different!  The way I determine domain is always returning the max value (for X that would be 100)

```
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(datafiltered, function (d) { return parseInt(d.x) }) * 1.1]).range([0 + margin, w - margin]),
```

Is there a way to reset this in the onclick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the scale (`x` in your case) with the new one (basically repeat the line that instantiates d3.scale) in the onclick handler and then redraw the visualisation. You shouldn't need to change any of the actual visualisation code if you overwrite the scale.

Comment: How do I redraw the visualization?  I thought I just needed to append circles, but that doesn't appear correct.  Here is the test code I was running after the dropdown was selected:

 $('#pickSet').on("change", function () {
                    vis.selectAll("circle")
                        .data([5])
                        .enter().append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", 3.33)
                        .attr("cy", 1.99)
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .attr("fill", "steelblue");
                });

Comment: Remove the `.enter().append(...)`. You should also replaced the hard coded `cx` and `cy` with calls to the scale you created earlier.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!
If anyone is looking for a full coded example, I got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottieb/cu523/

Comment: This works, but only if the datasets are the same number of elements.  Anything unequal either keeps data from the former, or does not use all the data in the later.  I think I need to append/remove, but am struggling because append only seems to add one element at a time:

http://jsfiddle.net/scottieb/cu523/

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).